# How to determine the very upper level the domain owner can control for a given domain name?

Tags: dns, subdomain

For a given domain name, i want to determine which level is the very upper level which the domain owner can control (the domain owner can make resolution changes at this level)

eg: for `www.abc.yahoo.com`, i want to get `yahoo.com` as the result)

I know there is a tld list at http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db, but there is some exception: `net.in`, `net.cn` etc.

Is there somewhere i can get the list of these registrable domains?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the domains handled by [CentralNic](https://www.centralnic.com/)?

Comment: thank you @rowland , maybe i found the right technical term: SLD/ccSLD, [ccSLD-godaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-are-second-level-domains-sld-and-country-code-second-level-domains-ccsld-335)  [SLD-wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain) Maybe I just need a list for these SLDs? I think not all these are handled by CentralNic, are they? Because net.cn seems not listed in this site.

Comment: Have you considered using [whois](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3912) for this?

Comment: Searching for the `SLD list`, I found [mozilla-TLD](https://wiki.mozilla.org/TLD_List) and [publicsuffix.org](https://publicsuffix.org/). Maybe this is what I am looking for.

Comment: @RowlandShaw Cannot figure a way out after executing `whois net.cn` and `whois net.in`.  The two results are quite different. But I found the above list according the url you sent to me.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time an easy way is to send a `SOA` query for the name you have and look at the response. If the name is a zone apex, you'll get a `SOA` record in the `Answer` section of the response. If it's not, you'll get a `SOA` record in the `Authority` section, and the owner name of that `SOA` record is the zone apex for the name you asked about. Here's an example of the latter case:

```
Kadath:~$ dig soa www.abc.yahoo.com @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3 <<>> soa www.abc.yahoo.com @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 44025
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.abc.yahoo.com.     IN  SOA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
yahoo.com.      0   IN  SOA ns1.yahoo.com. hostmaster.yahoo-inc.com. 2015101301 3600 300 1814400 600

;; Query time: 75 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 13 13:05:19 CEST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 107
```

This works for correctly set up zones. If you also want to cover broken setups, things get considerably less simple.

Comment: This seems to work in most cases. But there is at least one exception even though with correctly set up zones: when there is a CNAME record and the CNAME target is under a different tld, I think this method will fail.  An example: `www.baidu.com` is CNAMEd to `www.a.shifen.com.`

Comment: You get the SOA of the CNAME, yes. Hm. Which makes sense, technically. It also is correct, in the sense that it points out who actually has control of the content of the name `www.baidu.com`.